# Zend Framework 2 - Return JSON from Controller

Tags: php, json, zend-framework2

I have the following Json String:

```
var jsonString = '{"Users":[{"Name":"abc","Value":"test"},{"Name":"def","Value":"test"}]}';
```

I am trying to use ZF2's JsonModel class (Zend\View\Model\JsonModel) in the controller to render my view with the above JSON string. However, it seems to take only an array instead of a JSON String.

How do I make the controller return a JSON string?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to use a JsonModel since your json is already "rendered", so, you can set it directly in response object and return it:

```
/**
 * @return \Zend\Http\Response
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    $json = '{"Users":[{"Name":"abc","Value":"test"},{"Name":"def","Value":"test"}]}';

    $this->response->setContent($json);

    return $this->response;
}
```

That will short-circuit the dispatch event, so the application will return your response immediately, without calling the view layer to render it.

See http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.mvc.examples.html#returning-early

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `acceptableViewModelSelector` controller plugin

```
public function listAction()
{
    $acceptCriteria = array(
    'Zend\View\Model\ViewModel' => array(
        'text/html',
    ),
    'Zend\View\Model\JsonModel' => array(
        'application/json',
    ));

    $viewModel = $this->acceptableViewModelSelector($acceptCriteria);

    Json::$useBuiltinEncoderDecoder = true;

    $itemsList = $this->getMyListOfItems();

    return $viewModel->setVariables(array("items" => $itemsList));
}
```

The official doc : http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#zend-mvc-controller-plugins-acceptableviewmodelselector

Answer (score 1):

Another bonus : explanation of why using this plugin

[JsonStrategy security fix](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/pull/2410)

Answer (score 1):

Add in `module.config.php`:

```
'strategies' => [
     'ViewJsonStrategy',
 ],
```

Then you can return in controller json response:

```
return new JsonModel(['some'=>'data']);
```